# How to copy image from one excel to another in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have one excel which contains a logo(logo.png), and I want to read and edit the excel with openpyxl, and save it as another excel, but I found that when I use `load_workbook`, the image data seems to be lost.

Does openpyxl have any solution to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It quite clearly states in the [documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook) that images are not preserved in existing files.